# What specific tradesman should I call to rebuild a failing below grade retaining wall and the porch above it?

Tags: retaining-wall

The stairs to the exterior entrance to my basement run parallel to my house and under my kitchen porch, which has a trap door to access it.  The retaining wall, which runs parallel to the foundation, is made of unfilled cinderblock and is pushing inward.  I have been told that I need a mason to fix this, but I don't know what kind of a mason. Many of those that I find on line don't do work of this type.  So, the first question is what type of a mason would handle something like this.
Question 2) I think a better option would be a general contractor, since the porch will need to be fixed as well.  But the term general contractor seems to be very broad.  When I look for general contractors online, the people that come up run the gamut from painters, to roofers, to siding installers, to home builders.  Is there some more specific term I should use to find what I'm looking for?

Comment: You'd want a retaining wall or foundation contractor.

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: I'm in the United States.